# GitHub overriding markup language?

Tags: github, github-linguist

I'm using a markup language called AsciiDoc (`*.adoc`). I'd like to name my `*.adoc` files as `*.txt` [^1]. However, then GitHub (of course) doesn't draw `.txt` files as `.adoc` files.

So I tried to override the file types using `.gitattributes` as this:

```
*.txt linguist-language=AsciiDoc
```

But it didn't work. Any help? Thanks.

---

[^1]: Since Dropbox doesn't support editing `.adoc` files, I'm using `.txt` for AsciiDoc files.

Comment: Are your files correctly detected as AsciiDoc in language statistics?

Comment: My repo language was blank, so actually I was not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `linguist-language` correctly syntax highlight the file but fail to render markup. I've found that [emacs and vim modelines](https://github.com/github/linguist#using-emacs-or-vim-modelines) actually works for rendering markup though.

So a workaround would be to add the following in each txt files :

```
////
vim:ft=asciidoc
////
```

or if you prefer emacs :

```
////
-*- mode: asciidoc;-*-
////
```

Checkout [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/6b8f0c82a5293f9f1a1b04994865070f)

Comment: OMG I didn't expect such a complete answer! Much appreciated, thank you soooo much!!

Comment: Modelines and `linguist-language` should have the same effect on rendering AFAIK, so there's probably some issue with the `linguist-language` command here.